# Merge Json after several splits in Nifi

Tags: json, bigdata, apache-nifi, data-processing

I splitted my Json several times to avoid OOM errors. I've put a Wait processor to wait for all my records to the use a Merge content. Each FF has been assigned an attribute of the original file number of lines.

The wait processor should put the FF in wait until the notify increases the counter to the total number of lines.

However It seems that my Wait processor is not putting my FF in the Wait queue(it is not shown but there is).

Is there anything wrong in this peace of flow?

[image]

Comment: Show the parameters of wait processor. And if you are using MergeContent - you don't need wait.

Comment: yes I should need because i do multiple splits, the final merge only joins small pieces as it need the same fragment id

Answer (score 1):

You can do multiple merges by using UpdateAttribute after each Split to save the `fragment.*` attributes as something different, perhaps `fragment1.*`, `fragment2.*`, etc. Then you can restore each of them in reverse order with UpdateAttribute before each Merge, setting `fragment.*` to the `fragment2.*` attributes, then MergeContent, then set `fragment.*` to the `fragment1.*` attributes, then MergeContent, and so on.